# Efficient Algorithm for Comparing parts of lists containing sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In my application I need to compare parts of lists of sets to see if they contain the same elements. I have basically the following structure:

```
List 1 Index   Set
1              (1,5)
2              (3,7)
3              ()
4              (1,9,15)
```

I have something about 20 Lists an more than thousand sets in each list. The Sets in the list can be empty or can contain up to hundreds of elements.

I need to create the union of those sets for different intervals of my lists. 
So for example I want to compare intervals of the former list with the follwoing list:

```
List 2 Index    Set
1               (3,6,9)
2               (2)
3               (20)
```

Comparing Interval List 1 from 2 to 4 with Interval List 2 from 1 to 2 should give (3,9)

Currently I use a brute force method simply running throu both list an comparing each set. Is there a more efficient solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand how the lists relate to the sets. Does each list contain exactly one set, or does a list contain zero or more sets? Your example suggests the former, the question text suggests the latter.

Comment: Two sublists are equal iff they have the exact same sets in the exact same order?

Comment: @stakx, I clarified my question, thanks for the comment

Comment: So, you want to return a new set holding all the elements that can be found in any of the sets from list 1 and any of the sets from list 2? Just do a union of the sets of list 1 and of the sets of list 2 and then an intersection of those two sets.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to create for each such list, an auxiliary list, that contains histogram in each index of elements that appeared in sets up to now.

In your example:

```
List Index     histogram
1              [1=1, 5=1]
2              [1=1, 3=1, 5=1, 7=1]
3              [1=1, 3=1, 5=1, 7=1]
4              [1=2, 3=1, 5=1, 7=1, 9=1, 15=1]
```

Now, given two indices, `i,j` - you can create the union set of the sets in indices i,i+1,...,j by taking two histograms: `hist1=list[i-1], hist2=list[j]`, and return all elements `x` such that `hist1.get(x) < hist2.get(x)`, and get the union set without actually iterating the list.

For example, in the above list, if you want to find the union list for indices 2,3,4:

```
hist1=list[1] = [1=1, 5=1]
hist2=list[4] = [1=2, 3=1, 5=1, 7=1, 9=1, 15=1]
hist2-hist1 = [1=2-1, 3=1-0, 5=1-1, 7=1-0, 9=1-0, 15=1-0] = 
            = [1=1, 3=1, 5=0, 7=1, 9=1, 15=1]
union_set = {1,3,7,9,15}
```

This approach is especially useful when sets are considerably smaller than the lists, which seems to be your case.

Comment: A similar option with slightly different behaviour: create a binary indexed tree (BIT) on top of each list, where in each entry you store the union of the sets for the segment. Less storage needed than for the solution in this answer, but a little slower - you have to take log(k) unions for a segment of length k.